# vs c# Publish doesn't register my .dll

Tags: c#, dllregistration

I'm using Visual Studio to "Publish" my application, but when I install it on another PC I get an error for a missing .DLL

Is there a setting in the properties that I'm overlooking maybe?

This is very frustrating because on my development PC it works.

[image: Solution Explorer]

It is called FK623Attend.dll

[image: FKAttendDLL.cs Code]

This is the FKAttendDLL.cs Code

[image: DLL Properties]

This is the DLL Properties

The Original Program doesn't have the DLL in the solution... It was registered during installation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dll? How is it included in the project?

Comment: It is called FK623Attend.dll ... Please see picture

Comment: Is this a .net dll or a com dll?

Comment: That looks like it’s just added as a file and not as a reference. If it’s a managed dll it should be a reference. If it’s native it should have its properties set to be copied to output directory. Which one is it?

Comment: Can you show the properties of the _FK623Attend.dll_ file in VS?

Comment: It is a COM component, just copying the DLL is not enough.  Go back to the References of the project, select the type library and set its Isolated property to True.   Might work, but a component like this tends to also have a dependency on other unmanaged DLLs that have to be copied as well.  If you don't know then the only fail-safe way is to run the installer for the component on the target machine the same way you got it on yours.

Comment: @HansPassant how do you know it's a COM component? Given the p/invoke wrappers, I'd say it's a simple unmanaged DLL.

Comment: A little birdy called google told me.  I suppose it could do both, it isn't entirely unusual.  Getting the dependencies copied as well is required either way.

Comment: @HansPassant The DLL doesn't show in the type library

Comment: In the past I have registered any missing DLL with the "regsvr32.exe" command in cmd but I would like it to be done when Installing The Application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on the dll and go to properties. then set "Copy to Output directory" to " always copy" .then publish... Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

If it is a managed dll (.NET assembly) it should be added as a reference to the project and not as a file. If it’s a native DLL that just needs to be included, check the properties of the file and make sure the settings for copying are either Copy always or Copy if newer and type is Content. Otherwise the file is ignored.

Comment: It is a external DLL that needs to be registered... Please see the 2nd Picture that I will add to my question now